# Make an overlay for a horizontally centered image without fixed width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" />
    <div class="overlay">
       <div class="insides">more elements here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS code:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 88vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;  
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; 
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
```

My requirements are as follows:

1. Make image fill the available vertical space and center it horizontally. (Works)
2. Make image overlay of the same size as the image - without using an absolute `width` attribute. (Does not work - problem)
3. Fix icons to specific spots on the image. (Using percentages for `top` and `left` attributes ... Not sure if this is going to be as easy as I currently think.)

How can I have it all - a horizontally centered image expanded to fill the vertical space, an exact overlay and elements fixed to specific spot of the image?

While I would prefer a CSS hack, a Javascript solution will be considered, too, in case the width of the image needs to be transferred to the overlay programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to wrap the Image and the Overlay in a div and center that.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 88vh;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.imagecontainer
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.image {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class='imagecontainer'>
        <img class="image" src='imageurlhere'/>
        <div class="overlay">
           <div class="insides">more elements here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this, the Image will set the width of its parent and in doing so also the width of the Overlay.

Comment: Merci very much!